# compare two different formats csv fils with python

Tags: python, file, csv

I need to compare two different formats CSV files, the first file contains hostname, and IP address and the second file contains hostname, IP address, OS type, and uptime.
the objective is to take the hostname from the first file and compare it with the hostname from the second file and if ok the code gives me OS type and uptime.
this is my first test of code.

```
import sys

# f = sys.stdin
# If you need to open a file instead:
f_vm_srv = open('serveurs.csv')
f_srv_list =  open('fqdn-ip.txt')

for line1 in f_srv_list:
    hostname=line1.strip().split(";")
    for line in f_vm_srv:
        fields = line.strip().split(";")
        if fields[0] == hostname[0]:
            print (fields[12])

f_vm_srv.close()
f_srv_list.close()
```

but this code gives me just the first line of result.

Comment: first read all lines at least for inner loop because it will not read again lines from file when it get end of file (it means when you run second time inner loop)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing your code to be:

```py
import sys

# f = sys.stdin
# If you need to open a file instead:
f_vm_srv = open('serveurs.csv')
f_srv_list =  open('fqdn-ip.txt')

# read in the lines from the file
f_svr_list_lines = f_srv_list.readlines()
f_vm_srv_lines = f_vm_srv.readlines()

for line1 in f_svr_list_lines:
    hostname=line1.strip().split(";")
    for line in f_vm_srv_lines:
        fields = line.strip().split(";")
        if fields[0] == hostname[0]:
            print (fields[12])

f_vm_srv.close()
f_srv_list.close()
```

You could also look into reading you files in as Pandas DataFrames (see tha pandas [`read_csv` function](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)).

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to have to work a lot with csv in python and need to perform complex operations on then, then I strongly advise you get familiar with [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/).

You will be able to easily load your 2 files with `read_csv` and easily extract columns with using the `["column_name"]` operator.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **Pandas** library, useful to read csv.

Suppose that *file1* is the file that contains IP and hostname and the other file is *file2*. Moreover, I suppose that both files are composed like:

```
IP_value;hostname_value //file1
IP_value;hostname_value;OStype_value;uptime_value //file2
```

So, I read the csv files:

```
import sys
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_csv('file1.csv', sep=';', names=['ip', 'hostname'])
df2 = pd.read_csv('file2.csv', sep=';', names=['ip', 'hostname', 'ostype', 'uptime'])
```

Now, two `Dataframe` objects has been created. You iterate the `df1` over `df2` and if the `ip` of the `df1` is equal to the `ip` of the `df2`, you can do what you want.

Just a hint: you can access to the ip values using `df1['ip']`!

```
for ip1 in df1['ip']:
    for ip2 in df2['ip']:
        if ip1 == ip2:
            //Your code
```

An alternative is to use the function `where` of the *Numpy* library or the function `merge` of the *Pandas* library.

In particular, the function `merge` is useful if you want to check equals values on a certain column. You will merge both Dataframes (in your case `df1` and `df2`) in a new Dataframe (`df3`):

```
df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['ip'], how='inner')
```